# Function similar to split

Tags: python

Hello guys I'm trying to creat a function that works similarly to split() function but I'm unable to make it count " " as an item and seperate it
here is my code:

```
def mysplit(argstr, delimitor):
    A = ""
    B = []
    for i in argstr, delimitor: 
        if i != " ": 
            A += i 
        elif A != "": 
            B.append(A) 
            A = "" 
    if A != "": 
        B.append(A)
    return B 
print(mysplit('abc def',' '))
```

Comment: The loop `for i in argstr, delimitor` doesn't do what you probably expect it to do. I recommend you `print()` the value of `i` inside the loop to see (e.g. `print(f'i = "{i}"')`)

Comment: Just use `for i in argstr:` and then use `if i != delimitor:`

Comment: It works if I did it that way but I need " " as a third item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that your for loop is ill defined.

What are you looping on? You are trying to look at argstr character by character. The delimitor is a constant.

Result:

```
def mysplit(argstr, delimitor):
    A = ""
    B = []
    for i in argstr: 
        if i != " ": 
            A += i 
        elif A != "": 
            B.append(A) 
            A = "" 
    if A != "": 
        B.append(A)
    return B 
print(mysplit('abc def',' '))
```

Another problem you have is that you aren't actually using the delimitor at all, instead redefining it to be " " in your code. An improvement would be:

```
def mysplit(argstr, delimitor):
    A = ""
    B = []
    for i in argstr: 
        if i != delimitor: 
            A += i 
        elif A != "": 
            B.append(A) 
            A = "" 
    if A != "": 
        B.append(A)
    return B 
print(mysplit('abc def',' '))
```

It's possible to make your code even cleaner, but this way it should already work properly.

I see that you are insistent on wanting a ' ' in your result array. First I must warn you that this isn't consistent with what str.split does, so if you want to imitate str.split, you shouldn't do that.

But if you want it, here is a simple solution to it:

```
def mysplit(argstr, delimitor):
    A = ""
    B = []
    for i in argstr: 
        if i != delimitor: 
            A += i
        elif i == delimitor:
            if A != "": 
                B.append(A) 
                A = ""
            B.append(delimitor)
    if A != "": 
        B.append(A)
    return B 
print(mysplit('abc def',' '))
```

Comment: It's not taking " " as a third item that's the problem

Comment: You mean you want it to return ['abc', ' ', 'def']? That's not how string.split works, but you could just add elif i == " " and handle that case there.

Comment: @HAZEM I gave you a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

because of this line:

```
for i in argstr, delimitor:
```

You're telling the for loop to iterate over those two variables, so it takes the entire string in `argstr` as the first iteration.

replacing it with:

```
for i in argstr:
```

does what you want.